# Google Cloud Monitoring Agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to install the agent for monitoring and keep getting this error.  Can anyone help with some direction on this?

> Connection to 34.125.xxx.xxx port 22 timed out
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH into the instance. It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again. If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.

I tried allowing all traffic from host access. But it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

After further research I was able to resolve this by manually installing the agent using this article.  It worked!

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation